# Mean output returning NA despite input raster having data

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, terra, mean

I have various raster files. I am using following code in R to calculate mean of all the cell values of a raster file. For some rasters, it is giving NA value, however the rasters do have the data.

What could be the reason for this and how can I resolve it?

```
install.packages("terra")
library(terra)
setwd("F:/Test1")
ff = list.files(path="F:/Test1/", pattern=".tif$", full.names=TRUE)
rl = lapply(ff, function(x) rast(x))
means1 = lapply(rl, function(x) global(x, 'mean'))
means2 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, means1)

write.csv(means2, 'F:/Test1/avg.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `na.rm=TRUE` to accommodate NAs in your raster.

```
means1 = lapply(rl, function(x) global(x, 'mean', na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your rasters have the same extent and resolution you can simplify this to

```
r <- rast(ff)
global(r, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)
```